# Issues accessing an object's array values - returns null or 0s

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dojo, arcgis

The function below should return an array of objects with this structure:

```
TopicFrequency = {
                name: "Chemistry", //This is dependent on topic
                data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] //This would be real data
            };
```

so when I do this:

```
myData = this.getChartData("line");
```

it should return two objects:

```
{name : "Chemistry", data : [1,2,3,4,51,12,0,0, 2,1,41, 31]}
{name : "Math", data : [0,0,41,4,51,12,0,0, 2,1,41, 90]}
```

so when I do `console.log(myData);` it's perfect, returns exactly this.

However when I do `console.log(myData[0].data)` it returns all 0s, not the values. I'm not sure what this issues is known as, and my question is simple what is this problem known as?

Here is the full function. Somethings were hardcoded and other variables (notable server and queryContent) removed. Those parts worked fine, it is only when manipulated/retreiving the returned array's values that I run into problems. Note this is async. so not sure if that is also part of the problem.

```
getChartData: function (chartType) {     
    var TopicsFrequencyArray = new Array(); 
        timePairs = this.newIntervalSet("Month"); 
        topicList = new Array("Chemistry", "Math");//Hard coded for now
        var queryCopy = {
            //sensitive information
        };
        for (i = 0; i < topicList.length; i++) {
            var TopicFrequency = {
                name: null,
                data: this.newFilledArray(12, 0)
            };
            j = 0;
            TopicFrequency.name = topicList[i];

            while (j < timePairs.length) {
                queryCopy.filter = TopicFrequency.name;
                //additional queryCopy parameter changes made here
                var request = esri.request({ url: server, content: queryCopy, handleAs: "json", load: sucess, error: fail });
                j = j + 1;
                function sucess(response, io) {
                    var topicCountData = 0;
                    query = esri.urlToObject(io.url);
                    var dateString = query.query.fromDate.replace("%", " ");
                    dateString = dateString.replace(/-/g, "/");
                    dateString = dateString.split(".");
                    date = new Date(dateString[0]);
                    dojo.forEach(response.features, function (feature) {
                        if (feature.properties.count > 0) {
                            topicCountData = feature.properties.count;
                        }
                        TopicFrequency.data[date.getMonth()] = topicCountData;
                    });
                }
                function fail(error) {
                    j = j + 1;
                    alert("There was an unspecified error with this request");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
            TopicsFrequencyArray.push(TopicFrequency);

          }
},
```

Comment: It certainly does not seem like the full source of the function, as it ends with the closing brace of the `for` loop.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: lanzz - I have updated the code sections of the post.

Comment: Matt - I haven't tried that yet, as I'm not a great JS developer. I have through trial and error narrowed the problem to the function sucess (response, io) {...} portion. It functions (i.e TopicsFrequencyArray[0].name - "Chemistry", but TopicsFrequencyArray[0].data = [0,0,0,0....].).